# Steel rod horizontal strength

Tags: steel

I'm doing a repair project where I'll be using steel rod cantalievered out to 4'. Can anyone tell me approximately how much weight 1 1/2 and 2" steel rod can carry at 4'?. The deck won't weigh a lot but I'm needing someone who knows these things to provide an answer. I'm a humble contractor who works mostly with wood. Thank you. Ken

Comment: Is it solid or hollow? If hollow, what is the wall thickness?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We probably won't be able to answer you, as this probably requires a structural engineer.

Comment: One pro to another: you need to cover your butt when you're being paid to do something, and it sounds like you are well into the lawsuit territory if this fails. Make the customer pay for an engineer, then you build it. If they won't pay, you walk away and don't have the threat of losing your shirt. If they pay and you build exactly what the engineer specifies, then you're golden.

Comment: Google 'Berkeley deck failure' if you want to know what happens to a general that cuts corners and kills people.